# ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h when using media pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to download the pdf from a website, I followed the instruction provided by scrapy website but I got this error:

```
File "/home/joseph/ENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 58, in _set_url
    raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h
2017-09-12 17:47:40 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing {'file_urls': 'https://www.sec.gov/divisions/corpfin/cf-noaction/2008/jpmorgan080409-405.pdf',
 'title': ('JPMorgan Chase & Co.',)}
```

**Settings.py**

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
'sec_scrape.pipelines.SecScrapePipeline': 300,
'sec_scrape.pipelines.JsonWriterPipeline': 800,
'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 1,
}

FILES_STORE = '/home/joseph/pdf'
```

**Items.py**

```
import scrapy

class LetterItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    file_urls = scrapy.Field()
    files = scrapy.Field()
```

**spider.py**

```
import scrapy
from sec_scrape.items import LetterItem

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "corporate_finance"
    allowed_domains = ["sec.gov"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.sec.gov/divisions/corpfin/cf-noaction.shtml']

def parse(self, response):
    for letter in response.xpath('//table[2]/tr/td[3]/ul[74]/li/a'):
        item = LetterItem()
        item['title'] = letter.xpath('text()').extract_first(),
        item['file_urls'] = response.urljoin(letter.xpath('@href').extract_first())
        yield item
```

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`file_urls` item attribute has to be list, while you set it to string (the URL of file to download). Change line

```
item['file_urls'] = response.urljoin(letter.xpath('@href').extract_first())
```

to

```
item['file_urls'] = [response.urljoin(letter.xpath('@href').extract_first())]
```

Comment: Oh So i need to add `[ ]` brackets. Thank you.